# Why is sendRedirect(String path) not throwing IllegalStateException?

Tags: redirect, tomcat7, java-ee-6, servlet-3.0

I've following code in my servlet

```
  public class RedirectingExceptionServlet extends HttpServlet {

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("Hello, response is being committed");
        out.flush();
        response.sendRedirect("redirectedExceptionServlet");
        System.out.println("Tried redirecting after committing response");
    }

}
```

Here, I'm trying to redirect after the response has been committed.

As per the specification [Send Redirect java doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#sendRedirect) sendRedirect(String) should throw IllegalStateException if you try to call sendRedirect(path) after response is committed

Rather i see a page with message : Hello, response is being committed

Another interesting thing is, i'm unable to see statement "Tried redirecting after committing response" in server console

Can someone pls explain me this behavior?

Env details : Windows 7, Tomcat 7.0.47, J2EE-6

Comment: what I learnt by experimenting few things is, once the container encounters out.flush();

it returns from there and doesn't execute remaining lines of code or simply ignores them.

Please correct if my understanding is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Once the container encounters out.flush(); it returns from there and doesn't execute remaining lines of code or simply ignores them and this is true only in case there is no redirection before out.flush();

I have tried a lot of combinations. If someone is interested to have a look at these combinations, I can share them